# Primefaces Ajax requests async issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We have an Ajax issue in jsf/primefaces application.

Below is our scenario.

Primefaces Panel -> Panel Grid (2 columns) -> Label & primefaces input element (Textbox/Checkbox/RadioButton etc).
On change of any input element, we have an ajax call, we process the input and oncomplete of the respective ajax action with the help of an update attribute, we are updating the parent panel. Based on the answer we show/hide sub questions. While Ajax request is in progress, if user performs any subsequent action on other input elements (select checkboxes or radio buttons) on same page that request is not getting queued up. Once the panel gets updated for first ajax request, the data entered by user as part of second action is getting lost. We have tried to solve this issue by trying both async="true" and async="false".

Could anyone please suggest how to fix this issue with out blocking/locking the UI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use "p:blockUI".

See the example in the showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

Comment: BlockUI is the last option we would like to use. Users are not happy with blocking the UI. Is there anyway to add this new request to Ajax Requests queue?